# Cut and insert rows if criteria met in same WS

Tags: excel, vba

In the below image, building schedule and times are not in order. The hours are in 24hr and most often, if not all the time, the times between 20:00 and 23:59 are at the bottom of my sheet.

[image]

I need to have the entire row moved up above a certain time to put them all in order.

This is part of a bigger code that builds this sheet for me and this is the only problem I am having in completing it. I've tried to use macro recorder to see what is going on but this sheet data will change daily.

I'm looking for an answer on how to cut an entire row if a cell in that row contains a certain value and insert that cut row above an existing row also containing certain values. Example...If Row 23 column H has a value of 23:00 I need to move that row above row 20 that would have a value of 23:59 in column H. Any direction on any text or example that would contain this info is helpful!

Comment: How about sorting on column H?

Comment: I have tried multiple ways of sorting, though it does put the 23:00 first it will then be out of order after. Example..it would say 23.00, 04:00, 00:30 going down the H column. It should read...23:00, 00:30, 04:00

Comment: Can you store the times in datetime format? i.e.: `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm` . They will definitely sort in the correct order then. Assuming the schedule comes with a date as well... You can still display them as time if that's a problem.

Comment: @Dan, it can't be sorted that way. I assume that 00:30 and 04:00 is another day. So you have to include the date element as well.